# Image with `full-width` format not centered in Wagtail's RichTextField?

Tags: wagtail

I'm a beginner of Wagtail, and trying to follow the tutorial to build a blog website.

The question I have is about RichTextField, inserting an image in the editor, and I have chosen the "Full Width" format, expecting the image should be centered (as [said in the doc](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/editor_manual/new_pages/inserting_images.html#inserting-images-using-the-rich-text-field)).

However it's not centered, as shown in the picture below.

What's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs don't say anything about the image being centred. On the contrary, the [developer docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/images.html#images-embedded-in-rich-text) say:

> The CSS classes added to images do not come with any accompanying stylesheets, or inline styles. e.g. the `left` class will do nothing, by default. The developer is expected to add these classes to their front end CSS files, to define exactly what they want `left`, `right` or `full-width` to mean.

So, to centre the image, you could define a CSS rule such as:

```
img.full-width {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: My gosh, why wagtail lets people use these images' formats without providing a css? This is super confusing.